# App terminated by SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault

our app crashed, and I got the callStack, any can help?

```
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000195d6494c _sigtramp + 52
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000195551724 <redacted> + 564
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183c45074 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183d198a8 <redacted> + 1500
5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183c452d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
6   GraphicsServices                    0x000000018d4636fc GSEventRunModal + 168
7   UIKit                               0x000000018880afac UIApplicationMain + 1488
8   iphone-pay                          0x0000000100065784 iphone-pay + 38788
9   libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000195bb6a08 <redacted> + 4
```

`

Comment: Is this all exception stack you got? I guess there must be exception reason with this.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

A segfault happens when a memory read or write happens outside the memory space allowed to the application. They can be a terrible nuisance and difficult to debug... The problem is memory space can be corrupted and then fail only some predictable time later. The best general advice I can think of is to experiment with reproducability if possible, to figure out what happens *during potentially the entire application lifetime* to make a failure imminent. (Of course, the corruption *probably* happened shortly before the exception, and the access itself could be a legit exception.)